# how to add dynamic X axis values to highcharts

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

I have working highcharts in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chintamanil/y3Lx5qmb/
What i m doing is getting a stock price for displaying it every 5 seconds. I can plot the price on Y axis. But i want the time on X axis. I can get the time in the array as var tim = data.query.results.quote.LastTradeTime; 
I wan to assign this to the X axis. I tried

```js
            ary_time.push(tim);
            console.log(ary_time);
           // ary_time.push(tim)
            chart.series[0].setData(ary)
             chart.catogeries[0].setData(ary_time)
```

As you can see in the fiddle [If you let it run for 10 seconds] that i get y axis correctly. But X axis is not updated. Or its just numbers 1,2,,3 ..
IS there a way to make this dynamic as well.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574458/highcharts-x-axis-new-values ?  Example - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append/

Comment: At the beginning please fix this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of null  which appears in your code.

Comment: Cheery fiddle was really helpful. Sebastian I must have been playing with fiddle while you were trying it. I am a little new to it. My bad.

Comment: Now seems to working fine, am I right ?

Comment: Ya Sebastian. I found another fiddle and that helped. Thanks everybody for their response. I will start contributing more ...